# how can I loop on jquery An array of values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I loop on jquery An array of values?

For example:

I have two arrays divs, with id a[i] and b[i], now I want to write script like this:

```
$("#a\\[1\\]").keyup(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 13) { // enter == 13
       $("#b\\[1\\]").focus();
   }
});
```

now, how can I replace **"1"** with **var** like int

???

Comment: what is `a` ? and what are all the values inside it? And what do you want to achieve from that?

Comment: doing it in one loop would mean you would get a[1], b[1] then a[2], b[2] you would not get all b elements inside an a element. Having said that I don't think this would need a for loop at all but to know for sure we would need to see your HTML and how it is structured.

Comment: Use string concatenation: `$("#a\\[' + int + '\\]")`. However you would probably be better served by using a common class and then traversing the DOM to find the related `b[]` element.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please provide further information upon asking questions ([How to ask good questions?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). You need to clarify what you want to happen and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

```js
var i = 0;

jQuery('a:eq('+i+')').click(function(){
  jQuery('b:eq('+i+')').css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a> a1 </a>
<a>a2 </a><br/>
<b>b1</b>
<b>b2</b>
```